# Highest goal-difference for non-title winning side in top 5 European leagues?

Tags: football, trivia, records, la-liga, bundesliga

Tottenham Hotspur's goal difference of +60 in 2016/17 season is the highest in Premier League history for a non-title winning side. <sup>[Opta Stats](http://www.foxsportsasia.com/news/all-the-best-stats-from-the-premier-league-201617-season/)</sup>

What is the highest goal difference for non-title winning side in other European leagues such as La Liga, Bundesliga etc?

Highest goal difference for title winning side is:

Premier league: Chelsea 71 (2009-10)
La liga: Real Madrid 89 (2011-12)
Bundesliga: Bayern Munich 80 (2012-13)
Serie A: N/A
Ligue 1: Paris Saint-Germain 83 (2015-16)

Answer (score 4):

In the [2011-12 season of La Liga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011%E2%80%9312_La_Liga), Real Madrid set a record high goal difference of 89 goals on their way to the title. Barcelona finished runners-up and had an impressive goal difference of 85.

I have not found the statistics for the record goal difference across seasons, but if 89 is the record, 85 seems like it would be one of the highest goal difference for a non title winning side.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bundesliga the highest goal difference without the title goes to **Bayern Munich** as well. They scored a goal difference of +55 goals in the [Bundesliga season 2011/12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011%E2%80%9312_Bundesliga) beating the old record of +51 goals held by [themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1969%E2%80%9370_Bundesliga) and [Hamburger SV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979%E2%80%9380_Bundesliga).